# Why is this exception not being caught?

Tags: clojure

If I define the following function

```
(defn catcher [x] (try 
    (load-string x)
    (catch Exception e 
        (prn "caught"))) )
```

`(catcher "(+ 2 \"2\")")` => "caught"

but `(catcher "(keys [1 2])")`=> **ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry**

Normally both of these inputs throw ClassCastException, so why is only the first one being caught?

Comment: Why are you even using `load-string` out of curiosity? It looks like if you made this a macro, you'd be able to simplify it a bit.

Comment: I wanted a test bed for try/catch, and I'm not yet comfortable with macros.

Comment: You'd still use try/catch. It would look like ``(defmacro catcher [body] `(try ~@body catch Exception e (prn "caught")))`` (apparently you can surround code with double backticks to escape single backticks in comments).

Comment: @Carcigenicate +1 for the double backtick trick

Comment: @madstap Ya, I was glad I figured that one out before my edit period expired lol. I was going to do a self Q&A on Meta, but there's already a post describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the exception is happening when trying to *print* the result of `(keys [1 2])`.

```
(type (catcher "(keys [1 2])"))
=> clojure.lang.APersistentMap$KeySeq
```

Here you can see the expression is actually creating/returning a `KeySeq` without throwing/catching an exception. It's only when that `KeySeq` is *printed* that the exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at clojure.lang.APersistentMap$KeySeq.first(APersistentMap.java:168)
    at clojure.lang.RT.first(RT.java:685)
    at clojure.core$first__5107.invokeStatic(core.clj:55)
    at clojure.core$print_sequential.invokeStatic(core_print.clj:64)
    at clojure.core$fn__7021.invokeStatic(core_print.clj:174)
    at clojure.core$fn__7021.invoke(core_print.clj:174)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:233)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.pr_values$pr_values$fn$reify__784.send(pr_values.clj:35)
```

Notice in the stack trace this exception is originating from `KeySeq.first` method (which isn't being called until *after* your function has created and returned its value) when the REPL tries to realize the sequence for printing.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `[1 2]`, when you type it, is a clojure `vector` literal, not a Clojure `MapEntry`.  See these results:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ) )
(t/refer-tupelo)

(dotest
  (newline)
  (let [my-map      {:a 1 :b 2}
        map-entries (vec my-map)
        map-entry-1 (first map-entries)
        map-keys    (keys my-map)
        entry-1-key (key map-entry-1)
  ]
    (is= map-entries [[:a 1] [:b 2]] )
    (is= map-entry-1 [:a 1] )
    (is= map-keys [:a :b])
    (is= entry-1-key :a)

    (spyxx my-map)
    (spyxx map-entries)
    (spyxx map-entry-1)
    (spyxx map-keys)
    (spyxx entry-1-key)
  ))
```

with results:

```
Testing tst.demo.core

my-map        => <#clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap {:a 1, :b 2}>
map-entries   => <#clojure.lang.PersistentVector [[:a 1] [:b 2]]>
map-entry-1   => <#clojure.lang.MapEntry [:a 1]>
map-keys      => <#clojure.lang.APersistentMap$KeySeq (:a :b)>
entry-1-key   => <#clojure.lang.Keyword :a>

Ran 2 tests containing 4 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

The problem is that a `MapEntry` prints the same as a vector:

```
`[1 2]`
```

However, they are different types.  When you do `(load-string "[1 2]")` it is returning the vector, not a map, so you cannot call the `keys` function.

---

## Part #2

In your original question, you ask about

```
(catcher "(keys [1 2])") => Exception
```

I suspect that `load-string` is returning a lazy result, and this is not realized until after your code exits the try-catch block, and this is why the exception is not caught.